# Could not find Rubygem railties error on rails s after push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am using rails in windows, I pushed my app to heroku for the 1st time and after that each time I try run **rails s** on my local environment I get an error related to **Could not find Rubygem railties**. The push to heroku also seems to have failed as each time I try hit the app's url I get a "We are sorry but something went wrong page". Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause for this and what is the solution?

Comment: what's the output of `gem list`? What version of rails are you using?